# Could not find matching strategy for :yelp, but omniauth-yelp is installed

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, omniauth, yelp

When trying to start my Rails server with Yelp authentication, I get this error:

```
/var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/omniauth-1.2.1/lib/omniauth/builder.rb:50:in `rescue in provider': Could not find matching strategy for :yelp. You may need to install an additional gem (such as omniauth-yelp). (LoadError)
```

However, in my gemfile, I have the line

```
gem 'omniauth-yelp'
```

And ran

```
bundle install
```

In config/initializers/omniauth.rb, have the line

```
provider :yelp, ENV['yelp_consumer_key'], ENV['yelp_consumer_secret']
```

Why doesn't my application notice that omniauth-yelp is installed?

Comment: Not a direct solution for your  problem, but I have written another omnauth-yelp gem. I found the original one lacking in documentation and source code was also not available to fork. Browsing through the source code of this one may help you. https://github.com/dhaneshnm/omniauth-yelp